# Space complexity for a simple streaming algorithm

Tags: streaming, big-o, data-stream

I want to determine the space complexity of the go to example of a simple streaming algorithm.

If you get a permutation of n-1 different numbers and have to detect the one missing number, you calculate the sum of all numbers 1 to n using the formula n (n + 1) / 2 and then you subtract each incoming number. The result is your missing number. I found a german wikipedia article stating that the space complexity of this algorithm is O(log n). (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datenstromalgorithmus)

What I do not understand is: The amount of bits needed to store a number n is log2(n). ok.. but I do have to calculate the sum, tough. So n (n + 1) / 2 is larger than n and therefore needs more space than just log (n) right?

Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If integer A in binary coding requires N<sub>a</sub> bits and integer B requires N<sub>b</sub> bits then A*B requires no more than N<sub>a</sub>+N<sub>b</sub> bits (not N<sub>a</sub> * N<sub>b</sub>). So, expression n(n+1)/2 requires no more than log2(n) + log2(n+1) = O(2log2(n)) = O(log2(n)) bits.

Even more, you may raise `n` to any *fixed* power `i` and it still will use O(log2(n)) space. `n` itself, n<sup>10</sup>, n<sup>500</sup>, n<sup>10000000</sup> all require O(log(n)) bits of storage.